# Grass GIS: ArcGIS' "Raster to polygon" equivalent

Tags: raster, arcmap, grass-gis, vectorization

I've got a small clipped extent of a LANDSAT image and I need to have the single pixels as polygons in order to tell the overlap proportions of overlaying polygons.
In ArcGIS I used "Raster to polygon" without simplyfying polygons and used the "identity" tool then.

What would be a good equivalent in Grass GIS?

For "raster to polygon", I found "r.to.vect", but Grass always complains that the raster is "not properly thinned". I didn't understand what 'r.thin' does and I don't want ANY changes in the raster values.
Can anybody help with a "clean" solution?

EDIT:
According to Micha's answer, here's an illustration of what my final goal is:
[image]

Comment: According to the [docs](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass71/manuals/r.to.vect.html) thinning is for line features. Did you remember to select "area" as the feature type in r.to.vect? (I just did a test on a random raster and it didn't complain on either type, so I'm not certain about this.)

Comment: @RobSkelly is right, specify feature=area

Comment: That was the error! Beginner's mistake, sorry and thank you forthe answers!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

According to the [docs](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass71/manuals/r.to.vect.html) thinning is for line features. Remember to select "area" as the feature type in r.to.vect.

Answer (score 1):

I think gdal_polygonize might help you. It will convert a raster to vector format (GML, shapefile, etc). By default it connects the cell that have same values, but from your description, it should not be a problem.

This text comes from the official site:

> This utility creates vector polygons for all connected regions of
>   pixels in the raster sharing a common pixel value. Each polygon is
>   created with an attribute indicating the pixel value of that polygon.
>   A raster mask may also be provided to determine which pixels are
>   eligible for processing.

Below is a example converting a piece of raster to GML:

```
$ gdal_polygonize.py srtm_36_02.tif srtm_36_02.gml
Creating output srtm_36_02.shp of format GML.
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

[]

Comment: Okay, sounds nice, but how can I use this in Grass Gis?

Comment: You can run this command from your command line (Windows, Mac or Linux). See updated of my response.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's a useful alternative!!! (unfortunately I don't have enough reputation yet to upvote...)

Comment: No problem :) Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you final goal is to total raster values for each vector polygon. It's worth pointing out that the GRASS module `v.rast.stats` does just that.

Comment: Actually, it's the other way around...I want to know what the area contributions of the polygons to one LANDSAT pixel are. Maybe the little illustration in the edit helps